# Tensorflow Object Detection Api Box co-ordinate

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I used tensorflow object detection api on a  custom object. The models works perfectly but now i want to know the co-ordinates of the boxes. Is there a way to know the co-ordinates of the boxes for every object detected??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Tutorial IPython notebook,  there is the code they use to do the detection ([link to github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)):

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      image = Image.open(image_path)
      # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      # result image with boxes and labels on it.
      image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
          [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
```

They get the coordinates stored in the boxes variable.

Comment: yes they are normalized. They are in shape:  [[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax][...]]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: When this answer fits your needs, would you please accept it so that others can see the result faster? thank you!